# Cannot get char array based on the given integer

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    char vote[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&vote[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",vote[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't get second value, after getting first value it prints the first value .
If I give `3` for `n` it have to get three `char` values and it have to print that three `char` values , but code does not work properly for that.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer problem in `scanf`. Adding a space in the `scanf` because `%c` does not skip white space and terminate.

`scanf(" %c",&vote[i]);` instead of `scanf("%c",&vote[i]);`

Comment: An explanation of *why* that is required would improve the answer.

Comment: tanq rsp.....it helps me